# Retrieve image uploaded to firebase storage and use that URL in my React native expo code

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-storage

I'm a little confused how to upload an image from firebase storage into my app. I already have a place holder URL that works fine with another website's URL that acts as the button wallpaper.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate(HGSQ)}>
          <SwiperC imageUri={{uri:'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1473496169904-658ba7c44d8a?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2100&q=80'}} name='Hot Girl Summer'/>
          </TouchableOpacity>
```

So now to save storage on my App, I was wondering how to use the URL from the saved picture I uploaded to firebase. Would I have to use this code?

```
import storage from 'firebase/storage'; 
...
const imageURI = await storage().ref('myFolder/myFileName.jpg').getDownloadURL();
...
```

I tried doing this, but it kept saying the error "unexpected reserve word 'await'." Also just mentioning I already have set up the config for firebase in my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `await` without function

```
const getImageURI = async () => await storage().ref('myFolder/myFileName.jpg').getDownloadURL();
```

More about async/await you can know from MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

Comment: Thanks man i appreciate it! Sorry to ask again but would i then have to then switch imageUri to getImageURI instead? and also would i switch the place holder uri with the location of the picture in my firebase storage that it gives me or  'myFolder/myFileName.jpg'. thanks again for your help im actually a pharmacy student whos been teaching myself how to code for the last 6 months lol

Comment: you must use `getImageURI` and call because this function, example `<Image source={{ uri: getImageURI()  }} />`